# Two languages in sqlite database - Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have simple database - one table with 6 collumns. 3 of them i want have in two languages.

Is it possible to do it automatically ? Like add language prefix to collumn and it will choose language(_EN,_PL) that user use ? It will work ?

I must have everything in one database, because I copy it to users device.

I can' t find information about it, thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that isn't how SQLite DBs work even with Android's localization features. You can do it with `strings.xml` (for example) by creating...

```
/res/values/strings.xml
/res/values-pl/strings.xml
```

...and so on but databases and queries work on absolute column names.

The best way of doing this I can think of is to identify the local language and simply use the abbreviation as a suffix or prefix when building queries etc.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpfull. What i do: I define tableName in strings.xml and i use this name to fill sql statement.

Comment: @kolek : Glad I could help. Yes, using localized strings.xml to get the table name is a very good idea.